# Xamarin + ASP WebAPI + ASP MVC - which architecture is best?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I'm not found answer for my question - and opened this topic.

So I want develop project.

**Database:**

Or Couchbase or SQL Server (right now it is not important, but I think it will be Couchbase)

**Website:**

Asp .NET MVC + Angular etc. - Simple Website

**Web Api:**

ASP .NET WebAPI

```
**Mobile Application (This is hard side for me)**
```

I'm a good C# developer - it's a reason why I want write Application by Xamarin.
If its bad idea - tell me (and tell me WHY IS BAD IDEA)

if is good framework, I have a few question:
1) How work with API
2) Or I need write for each platform(iOS, Android, WP) - service (like WCF) = (3 services?)

3) Which way better for Authentication (I want give to user option Registration by FB, Google, What's Up, etc...)

I dont know, maybe you can give me links for good topics, or same question here (I'm not found)
Or maybe you can give me a name of good course on Lynda or plularsight?

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, you should post this type of question at [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. But hope i will get good recommendation here too.

Comment: With Xamarin you should be able to share your code that deals with the API (as well as most of your business logic) for all three platforms. With the UI you have a choice of either using Xamarin.Forms where you would share a lot of that code or do it for each platform separately (even if you use Xamarin.Forms you can still do parts of it separately for each platform as needed). The nice thing is even the platform specific bits you are able to do in C#.

Answer (score 3):

1. With ASP.NET Web API you can make a REST web service working through HTTP protocol. Any platform which supports HTTP protocol, can consume your web service.
2. You need only one web service for all platforms.
3. In current ASP.NET Web API version, you can use ASP.NET Identity which supports local account and external account through OAuth.

For example, this [post](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-service-from-android/) shows how to consume a ASP.NET Web API in Android. And this [one](http://hintdesk.com/c-use-asp-net-identity-external-authentication-with-desktop-application/) is about how to use external account for authentication. There're some more posts in that blog discussing about ASP.NET Web API, just spend some minutes flying over it, you'll find some useful infos.

I have no experience with Xamarin so I can't say anything about it. I write mobile app in their native platforms (Android with Java, IOS with Objective C++).

Comment: P.S - REST web service - do you mean = .asmx???
Maybe WCF will better ??

Comment: @David: No, I don't mean .asmx or WCT. REST web service communicates typically over HTTP Protocols and provides for each resource an endpoint which can be consumed over HTTP verbs. The WCF gives you many possibilities to publish your resources over many types of bindings. The ASP.NET Web API

Comment: If you plan to consume your web service only over HTTP, I prefer to use ASP.NET Web API because it's a part of ASP.NET and will be soon able to run over Linux (maybe more stable and  securiable). I myself find that ASP.NET Web API is much more better than WCF for writing REST web service.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And how I know ASP already run over Linux - Microsoft was started their Open Source project last month